# How do I fix Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. In my Express App?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I keep getting the following error when I run `PUT` request to update a document in my mongodb database using mongoose.

```
PUT /books/5ebe23e548b95a15c006f9f7 500 8.598 ms - 5
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

Here is how I am writing my api endpoints. All the other methods work `GET`, "POST", and "DELETE". The only one that is not working is `PUT`. Here is my 'PUT' endpoint: `http://localhost:5006/books/5ebe23e548b95a15c006f9f7` and here is the payload

```js
{
    "title": "This is the Third book title",
    "description": "Third book description",
    "image": "",
    "price": 33
}
```

And here is the who file.

```js
const createError = require("http-errors")
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const logger = require("morgan")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Books = require("./models/books")

const app = express()

app.use(logger("dev"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected"))

// API's
app.post("/books", (req, res) => {
  const book = req.body

  Books.create(book, (err, books) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.json(books)
  })
})

app.get("/books", (req, res) => {
  Books.find((err, books) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.json(books)
  })
})

app.delete("/books/:_id", (req, res) => {
  const query = {
    _id: req.params._id
  }

  Books.remove(query, (err, books) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.json(books)
  })
})

app.put("/books/:_id", (res, req) => {
  const book = req.body
  const query = {
    _id: req.params._id
  }
  // if the field doesn't exist $set will set a new field
  const update = {
    "$set": {
      title: book.title,
      description: book.description,
      image: book.image,
      price: book.price,
    },
  }
  // when true return the updated document
  const options = {
    new: true
  }

  Books.findByIdAndUpdate(query, update, options, (err, books) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.json(books)
  })
})
// END API's

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"))
})

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404))
})

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {}

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500)
  res.render("error")
})

module.exports = app
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error comes from this line `res.render("error")` since you haven't setup any **view engine**. Change it temporarily to `res.send('error')` and it should work. 
Also the error handler is called which means there's some other error in your app.

Comment: @Molda I still get the 500 error `PUT /books/5ebe23e548b95a15c006f9f7 500 11.681 ms - 5`

Comment: So instead of `if (err) { throw err ...` do `if (err) console.log(err)` to see the actual error in command line

Comment: Ok this is the error I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

Comment: you got res, req instead of req, res

Comment: Damn!! I just realized that. Now it works thanks.

Comment: Cool also you should see the line number where the error occured. Hint: first argument in the callback function `app.put("/books/:_id", (res, req) => {` is not res but req. You got them the other way round. Bad -> `(res, req)` Good -> `(req, res)`

Comment: It happens to everyone, dont worry! Keep it up dude!!!

Comment: Yeah lol thanks @IgnacioElias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with your code, it seems preety good to me. 
This is a piece of text from the mongoose docs

`Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command by a document's _id field. findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...).`

Since you are using the findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) format, maybe you should use the id string argument instead of the query object

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: just replace the query declaration with this `const query = req.params._id `